# Node. get data from database and and make post request with results

Tags: javascript, node.js, spotify

I have a list of users in a database. They have initially been given an access_token, when signing up to db, but as this expires I need to create a new access_token through a refresh_token which has also been saved in the db against a user.

I need to make a POST request to an endpoint to access get a new access token.

I am trying to loop over each row in the database and get a new access_token this way. When there is one user it works perfectly, but when there is more than one user in the `users` array each `user` is the same, i.e. the last user in the database table. I guess the request isn't finished and it is trying to send a new request or something like that.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

```
app.get('/get-users', function (req, res) {
    connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields) {
        if(err) console.log(err);

        for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            name = rows[i].name;
            userId = rows[i].userId;
            console.log(userId);// this gives the correct userid
            var authOptions = {
                url: url,
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
                },
                form: {
                    grant_type: 'refresh_token',
                    refresh_token: refresh_token
                },
                json: true
            };

            request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                    var access_token = body.access_token;
                    users.push({name: name, userId: userId, accessToken: access_token});
                    console.log(userId)//gives last entry in db
                }
            });
        setTimeout(function () {
           console.log(users)
         }, 3000)
        }
    });
   res.send('getting here');
})
```

Comment: You've asked this question 30min ago and it was closed : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884069/make-post-request-in-loop-node/40884140

Comment: @xShirase i know man, sorry! I wanted to get it working with one user first, as I wasn't 100% sure if that was the issue, but now i know it is. As I said though, the issue isn't sending the response to the browser, but getting the right data pushed into the `users` array. Thanks for your help too, i really appreciate it

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do though. you're refreshing all the user tokens in one go, every time?

Comment: in any case, get rid of the for loop, make a function that handles the POST requests, res.send when the function is done

Comment: @xShirase i have a list of `refresh_tokens` that need to be changed into `access_tokens`. that is actually working. I think the issue must be what u are saying with the function, but I'm not 100% sure how the function will look like and where it will be called/go in the js file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442426/solution-found-node-js-async-parallel-requests-are-running-sequentially this could help you if you want to run all your requests in parallel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        name = rows[i].name;
        userId = rows[i].userId;
        // ...
        request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
          // you're using name and userId here
        });
        // and also you use users here:
        console.log(users)
    }
```

Now, the problem is that no callback will get called (even for the first iteration) before **all** of the loop iterations finish.

So first of all, the `console.log(users)` will always get the value of `users` whatever it was **before** any `users.push()` took place.

Additionally, for **every callback** the value of `name` and `userId` will be the same - whatever it was after the last iteration of your `for` loop.

Your `name` and `userId` seem to be global variables, or they are defined in some outer scope. What you need to do is to use `let` to define them locally, so that they get fresh bindings for every loop iteration.

See a simple example to demonstrate what going on here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  x = 'Number ' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(x);
  }, 500*i);
}
```

It's not good because `x` is a global variable. Now with `var`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var x = 'Number ' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(x);
  }, 500*i);
}
```

Still not good because there is only one bonding for `x` shared for every iterations. Now with `let`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let x = 'Number ' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    console.log(x);
  }, 500*i);
}
```

It works because every iteration gets a new binding.

#### Update

Another thing is making sure that the you know when every `request.post` has ended so that you can send a response at the right time.

You can use [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) to help you with that. You can use promises and libraries like [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/) or [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) to help you with that. But you can also do a simple trick. If you want to know that you are inside of the last callback on the example that I showed above, you can count the invocations like this:

```
let current = 0, last = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  let x = 'Number ' + i;
  setTimeout(function () {
    if (++current === last) console.log('Last callback:');
    console.log(x);
  }, 500*i);
  last++;
}
```

This may not be the best way to handle complex situations but it demonstrates what is going on: the `last` variable gets incremented for every iteration and the callbacks are only registered at that time. Then the callbacks start firing one after another and you can increment the `current` variable every time a ne callback is fired and compare if that was the last one or not.

Now, a general advice: Use `let` (or `const`) every time instead of `var`. It's much more intuitive how it works. Of course you can use `var` if you know what you're doing but when in doubt use `let`.

Comment: thanks @rsp. so if i use `let` do you think that will work, or do i need to start adding callbacks aswell?

Comment: if i use `let` then I need to use `strict mode`, but i need `users` to be a global variable as i use it in two of my express endpoints. make sense?

Comment: @phantom Using `let` for `name`, `userId` and possibly `i` is a start. Another problem is the `console.log(users)` and `res.send` which need to take place after all of the callbacks end.

Comment: As for the globals, you may be able to use `global.users` or define `users` with `var users` or `let users` outside both of your handlers, like at the beginning of the file. If the handlers are in separate files then you may do it in a common file that is `require`d by both of them.

Comment: i know, but it seems as when i try and use let for `name`, `userId` and `i` I need to use strict mode which is then causing problems for `user`

Comment: i think i needed to define users at the start of the file :-)

Comment: this is great! thanks for your help. should i be using callbacks instead though? am i taking a bad approach?

Comment: @phantom I updated my answer with some ideas on how you can make sure that you are in the last callback and you can return the response. The most elegant way would be to use `async` or primises to handle situations like that but you can also count the invocations of callbacks as I showed and use the `if (++current === last)` trick at the end of your callback to run your `console.log(users)`. The timeout will work but if for some reason not all requests finish in those 3 seconds then you will print incomplete data if you're using the timeout.